# android webview client link click not working

Tags: android, webview

Im using
[RichEditorView](https://github.com/wasabeef/richeditor-android) to display html.
I have a html like below:

```
<p><a href=\"https:\/\/mylink.com\/WorkTemplate\/DataFlowInputForm\/2000\/VdjNTvjen02Rs9XmOzas6A\/3dRLHu8k4UeYQa5kGsGt8w\/KcP0d_JP5UCNmJuN0kKz3Q\" rel=\"noopener noreferrer\" target=\"_blank\">Here is link<\/a><\/p><p><span style=\"background-color: var(--main-bgr-color);\">...
```

It's display success in my webview, but can not click. Here is code:

```
 protected class EditorWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            Log.e("TAG", "shouldOverrideUrlLoading1:  " + url);
            String decode = Uri.decode(url);

            if (TextUtils.indexOf(url, CALLBACK_SCHEME) == 0) {
                callback(decode);
                return true;
            } else if (TextUtils.indexOf(url, STATE_SCHEME) == 0) {
                stateCheck(decode);
                return true;
            }

            if (url.startsWith("http://") || url.startsWith("https://")){
                mLinkClick.onLinkClick(url);
                return true;
            }
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            Log.e("TAG", "shouldOverrideUrlLoading2:  " + request.getUrl().toString());
            final String url = request.getUrl().toString();
            String decode = Uri.decode(url);

            if (TextUtils.indexOf(url, CALLBACK_SCHEME) == 0) {
                callback(decode);
                return true;
            } else if (TextUtils.indexOf(url, STATE_SCHEME) == 0) {
                stateCheck(decode);
                return true;
            }
            if (url.startsWith("http://") || url.startsWith("https://")){
                mLinkClick.onLinkClick(url);
                return true;
            }
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request);
        }
    }
```

When click i only get:

```
 shouldOverrideUrlLoading2:  re-state://
```

i want to get:

```
 shouldOverrideUrlLoading:  mylink.com...
```

Can anyone help my problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should try to load valid HTML into the `WebView`, to begin with... that's the `contentHTML` property. And also, you should use the Android version of the library instead - as the documentation you've linked hints for: https://github.com/wasabeef/richeditor-android